# Setting up a reliable, solitary, disk-backed server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-ec2

I've been migrating some servers to AWS and have a question about reliability.  I've read that instances can be [retired at random](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html), so I know I have to set them up with some kind of auto-scaling group/load balancer to make them reliable.  Thanksfully, Amazon has provided a [nice guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/web-app-hosting-intro.html) to setting up web apps. My problem with that guide is for "web apps" that maintain state on disk.  The specific example I'm working on right now is a RubyGems server using [maestrodev/geminabox](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/geminabox).  I'm fine with this being somewhat low availability (e.g. being down for an hour), but I don't want future generations to have to take manual steps when it inevitably falls over.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. Set up a load balancer for my gem server
2. Set up an auto-scaling group that knows how to bring it up, and configured it to keep 1 instance up at all times
3. Set up a route53 CNAME pointing to the LB
4. Attached persistent EBS volume to store the actual gems I upload

This last step is the one that I'm not sure how to automate in AWS, and indeed the idea of auto-scaling seems almost fundamentally opposed to it.  Still, I don't see why a DB/S3 should be the only place I'm allowed to store state if I don't really care about scaling up to X servers for load.

Also... Is there a faster way of doing what I'm trying to do?  This seems like an insane number of steps to set up a single server.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to automate the setup of an EC2 server? How to make a single server reliable?

Comment: How to make a single server reliable, and allow it to reliably store info on the local disk.  I'll change the question name if that's more clear.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not programming related. It might fit better on another site. I will say that you are probably asking the wrong question ("how to make a single server reliable", the answer to that is "you can't") but instead you should be asking how to easily recover a single server from failure. I would suggest looking into automated EBS snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is current state of your application. You can try to managed it over EBS, but I think it's complicated in general (limitations on attaching in same AZ i.e).
I can imagine you can trigger lambda that will create snapshot of EBS (here is up to you how you will managed later sync, I guess **rsync** may be a good solution).
Personally I would store files in S3 and sync to EBS, assuming EBS is preferable solution. If you like to avoid lambda for whatever reason you can use script AS execute on creation.

Regardless of approach I would strongly recommend to have source of truth file repo - **S3** for this is really well suited

Possibly upcoming Elastic File System (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/). It's acting as object storage file system (imagine scaling way S3 is doing) and same time you've got NFS interface.

If you can avoid moving EBS around - you cannot attach to multiple servers, you are limited to AZ where EBS lives and in general it's not as fast operation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a CloudFormation template.  I use Troposphere for this but as you are using ruby, this might be better https://github.com/bazaarvoice/cloudformation-ruby-dsl

This can do steps 1-4

To keep a backup of the uploaded stuff keep a regular snapshot of the EBS volume that the uploads are on.  I would run this as a cron job but there are lots of ways of doing it.  Might be better/ easier to have this as a seperate volume

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd be interested in instance [recovery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html)

As long as you are using a supported instance type (which seems to cover the recent types: c3,c4,m3,m4,t2,r3 ) in a VPC and you don't use any instance store volumes then you can set auto recovery as the action for a cloudwatch alarm. Normally this would be on the status check metric (which indicates a problem with the underlying hardware)

Recovery reboots the instance and moves it to new hardware. Clearly this will involve a few minutes of downtime. This may not help with a problem that affects an entire AZ (at least not until the AZ has recovered)

If this isn't enough and you want to stick with your original approach then I would address this by:

- periodically snapshotting the ebs data volume
- update the autoscaling launch configuration so that the blockdevicemapping specifies a new volume based on that snapshot.

Whenever your autoscaling group starts up, you'll get a volume with the most recent snapshot data attached (obviously you will lose data since the last snapshot)

In terms of making the snapshot, the easiest thing is probably a cronjob on the instance that calls the aws cli. You can configure your instance with an IAM role that will allow it to do this.

It's possible that your snapshot will capture your application in an inconsistent state. You can guard from some of this by freezing volume immediately before the snapshot (you can unfreeze as soon as the snapshot has started) but ultimately you need some cooperation from the application to be 100% sure.